# Is there any way of Accessing/ fetch application logs of AKS (Azure kubernetes Services) from outside or browser?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, logging, azure-aks

I have deployed a web application on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS). I want to generate Application logs of deployed web application of cluster like Log folder. I want to access those logs from LOG folder through browser or any other solution which I can easily share with developers to access logs from their system as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logging options, cloud-native solutions like **fluentD** and you can push the logs from **LOG** folder to **Elasticsearch** or **Azure** **logging** solution and you can watch the logs into dashboard.

Fluentd : https://www.fluentd.org/

Check out more at : https://logz.io/blog/kubernetes-log-analysis/

Comment: But we do not want to use any third party tool. So we need solution where we can access the logs on browser.

Comment: thn you can use the azure monitoring directly so AKS logs will be there in azure monitoring and watch logs in azure console it self. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/microservices/logging-monitoring